# ¿Por qué me da tiempo de espera caducado cuando llamo a un procedimiento desde una aplicación?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en visual studio 2010 con vb.net. Lo que me da error es la última línea de este código:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.SaxoniaConnectionString)
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
conn.Open()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedure"
SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd)
cmd.Parameters("@Referencia").Value = Me.ReferenciaComboBox.SelectedValue
cmd.Parameters("@SaldoMin").Value = Replace(Me.SaldoMinTextBox.Text, ",", ".")
cmd.Parameters("@SaldoMax").Value = Replace(Me.SaldoMaxTextBox.Text, ",", ".")
cmd.Parameters("@Denom").Value = Me.DenomReferenciaTextBox.Text
Dim adap As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
adap.Fill(dt) 'Esta linea da el error de tiempo de espera caducado
```

Si ejecuto la consulta del procedimiento directamente en el SQL Server Management Studio con los mismos parámetros que le paso en el código tarda 5 segundos.

Y ahora viene lo que no entiendo:
si hago un ALTER del procedimiento cambiando cualquier cosa, hago ALTER otra vez para dejarlo como en el caso inicial y ejecuto la aplicación deja de dar el error de tiempo de espera durante unos días. ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: me suena a "parameter sniffing"

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta ¿Y solución sabes cual es mejor? recompile, variables dummy...

Comment: lamentablemente es cosa de probar. Variables dummy solucionan parameter sniffing, pero te van a crear un plan de ejecución que no es necesariamente el mejor. Recompile al sp completo significa que siempre tiene que crear el plan de ejecución para todo el sp. Quizás usar el hint option recompile en la consulta con el problema sería lo mejor en este caso

Comment: Ah, se me olvidaba, en SQL Server 2016 hay un nuevo hint que se llama disable_parameter_sniffing, pero funciona de forma similar que los parámetros dummy

Comment: Gracias, iré probando todas las soluciones

Comment: De momento parece que era eso lo que me pasaba, que no me ha vuelto a pasar desde que puse variables Dummy, gracias. Si lo pones como respuesta le doy a aceptar respuesta, que desde un comentario no doy.

Comment: Ok, publiqué una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comportamiento que notas suena a "parameter sniffing". Este efecto se da porque un procedimiento almacenado guarda el plan de ejecución generado para los parámetros usados la primera vez que se ejecuta (si es que no se ha limpiado el caché).

De esta forma, cuando se ejecuta de nuevo, el plan de ejecución probablemente no es el óptimo.

Hay diferentes alternativas para solucionarlo, pero no hay una respuesta que sea la óptima para todos los casos, simplemente tendrás que probarlas:

- Usar variables "dummy". Esto soluciona "parameter sniffing", pero te van a crear un plan de ejecución que no es necesariamente el mejor.
- Usar "Recompile" al sp completo. Esto significa que el optimizador siempre tiene que crear un nuevo plan de ejecución para todo el sp
- Usar el hint "option recompile" en la consulta con el problema quizás sería lo mejor en este caso
- Desde SQL Server 2016 hay un nuevo hint: "disable_parameter_sniffing", pero sus resultados son similares a los obtenidos con las variables "dummy".

Probablemente las opciones con "recompile" te generen los mejores planes de ejecución, pero como decía, hay que probar las alternativas.

Answer (score 1):

El usuario con el cual estás llamando al Procedimiento almacenado desde tu aplicación puede no tener el permiso para ejecutar dicho Procedimiento (luego de realizar el ALTER).

Asegúrate de que el usuario pueda llamar a este procedimiento. Te conectas al SSMS con el usuario y ejecutas el Procedimiento almacenado al​ cual le diste un ALTER previamente.

Por lo general se define un usuario X para que pueda conectarse desde la aplicación, el cual tiene ciertos permisos nada mas, no es buena idea usar el usuario root.

Comment: El usuario que uso en ambos es el mismo, el root.

Comment: Entiendo. ¿que cambios hiciste con el Procedimiento almacenado ?. Proba primero cerrar tu aplicacion e iniciar de vuelta cuando haces el ALTER, también puedes probar bajar y subir tu Base de Datos.